# separating input into multiple variables in c++

Tags: c++

If I ask a user for an input that's separated by dashes, how can I store them into multiple variables? One for each part that is separated by the dashes.
for example, this doesn't work.

```
cout << "enter date" << endl;
// user inputs something like 11/11/1980
cin >> month
```

I understand the input is stored in the iostream but how can I store whats after the first slash

Comment: Nice example data, is 11 the month or the day?  What is the format, month first or day first?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should look into using the date tools that C++11 already provides to you.

time.h's `struct tm` has [it's own streaming operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time). So I'd do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    tm t;
    istringstream ss("11/11/1980");

    ss >> get_time(&t, "%m/%d/%Y");

    cout << t.tm_mon + 1 << ' ' << t.tm_mday << ' ' << t.tm_year << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why but it's noteworthy that `tm.tm_mon` is 0-based...

See also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time

Comment: and `tm.tm_year` is 1900 based

Answer (score 2):

I just got into the same situation, and I found this works.
Hope this is still useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    // This is to initialize variables:
    std::string mm,dd,yy;

    // Now get the input
    std::cout << "Enter the Date number: ";

    // Then split it using std::getline() with delimiter '/'
    // and assign them to relevant variables
    std::getline(std::cin, mm,'/');
    std::getline(std::cin, dd, '/');
    std::cin >> yy;

    std::cout << mm << " " << dd << " " << yy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store input in `string` (or char array) and then later separate you desired parts, for that purpose you can create a function which will take the `input string` as parameter and separate its parts.

Comment: Please don't recommend character arrays.  They are ugly and prone to buffer overrun or buffer overflow attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You could search the web for "c++ read date" for some examples.

One method is:

```
unsigned int month;
unsigned int day;
unsigned int year;
char         separator;
cin >> month >> separator >> day >> separator >> year;
```

But there are issues with that, such as having a space before the '/'.

Another method is to `fscanf` with a decent format string:

```
  fscanf(stdin, "%2d/%2d/%4d", &month, &day, &year);
```

but, that doesn't use the C++ streams.

You could use strings and `getline`:

```
std::string month_str;
std::string day_str;
std::string year_string;
std::getline(cin, month_str, '/');
std::getline(cin, day_str, '/');
std::getline(cin, year_str); // What's the delimiter here???
```